# Analog of template toolkit block-include in erb rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, block, erb, toolkit

What is the analog of template toolkit block-include in erb rails?
Or how to translate this code to rails erb (only one single file):

```
[% BLOCK hello %]
   Hello [% var %]!
[% END %]
[% INCLUDE hello var='World' %]
```

result:

```
   Hello World!
```

Comment: A partial with locals, maybe? I don't *think* ERb has block "macros" like that, although you could just use string interpolation.

Comment: Or a helper, also not a single file.

Comment: Rails has `content_for` and `yield` which have a somewhat similar purpose http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#understanding-yield